# How to align child image with submit button

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I am using for my submit button.  No matter what I do the image aligns slightly to the right and lower than the button "frame" on the displayed page, code follows:

```css
button {
  width: 114px;
  height: 30px;
}

button img {
  border: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="acctmntbtn">
    <img name = "acctmntimg" src = "btns/view.jpg" width = "114" height = "30">    
    </button>
```

How do I get the image to align perfectly over the button?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to not have to worry about the visual "frame" of the button not lining up exactly with the image all you have to do is set the button attribute in CSS3 to border : none;

Comment: Ahhh, okay. I updated my answer. I've added "display:contents;" in the CSS for button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and height style for the < button > element.

```css
button
{
 display: contents;
}
button img
{
  border: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="acctmntbtn">
<img name="acctmntimg" src="btns/view.jpg" width="114" height="30">    
</button>
```

Comment: Bingo!  When I add border : none; to the button attributes I don't see it at all.  That's good enough!